# I need a way to keep selected combobox values after page refresh

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I have a number of comboboxes they all look like this:

```
<select name="cb1" size="1" id="kuz1" style="position:absolute;left:19px;top:96px;width:144px;height:69px;z-index:2;">
<option>Пусто</option>
</select>
```

then i obtain options for them from txt file using a simple js script.

I need a way to store selected information and keep it even if page is refreshed. I tried to use localstorage and cookie options, but they didn't work for some reason.

i tried to set variables like this `var kuz1var=document.getElementById('kuz1').value;`
but console always returns as "undefined"

I need somebody's advice to resolve this issue

Here is how i managed to obtain values for comboboxes

```
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script>
  $.get("мм.txt", function (data) {
    var lines = data.split('\n').map(function(line){
      return line.trim();
    });
    var select = $("select[name=cb1]")
    var optionCounter = 0;
    var currentGroup = "";
    lines.forEach(function(line){
      if(line.endsWith(" -")){
        currentGroup = line.substring(0, line.length - 2);
        optionCounter = 0;
        select.append("<optgroup id='" + currentGroup + "' label='" + currentGroup + "'>")
      } else if(line === ""){
        select.append("</optgroup>");
      } else {
        select.append("<option type='checkbox' id='" 
            + (currentGroup + optionCounter) + "' name='" 
            + (currentGroup + optionCounter) + "' value='" 
            + line + "'>" + line + "</option>");
      }
    });
    console.log(lines);
  });
  </script>
```

Comment: Not sure if I can answer your question, have you tried using `document.cookie` for persistent storage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason the right answer was deleted, so here's the answer

```
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script>
$.get("мм.txt", function (data) {
            var lines = data.split('\n').map(function(line){
                return line.trim();
            });
            var select = $("select[name=cb1]")
            var optionCounter = 0;
            var currentGroup = "";
            lines.forEach(function(line){
                if(line.endsWith(" -")){
                    currentGroup = line.substring(0, line.length - 2);
                    optionCounter = 0;
                    select.append("<optgroup id='" + currentGroup + "' label='" + currentGroup + "'>")
                } else if(line === ""){
                    select.append("</optgroup>");
                } else {
                    select.append("<option type='checkbox' id='" 
                        + (currentGroup + optionCounter) + "' name='" 
                        + (currentGroup + optionCounter) + "' value='" 
                        + line + "'>" + line + "</option>");
                }
            });
        
            // Get the selected value from local storage
            var cb1val = localStorage.getItem("cb1val");
            if (cb1val) {
                select.val(cb1val);
            }
        
            select.on("change", function () {
                // Save the selected value to local storage
                localStorage.setItem("cb1val", select.val());
            });
            console.log(lines);
});
</script>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).